# Portable class library and resx localization

Tags: c#, localization, windows-store-apps, portable-class-library

I have Portable class library, where I have resx files containing localization strings (Resources.resx, Resources.en.resx, Resources.de.resx ). Then I use this resources in the PCL LocalizationViewModel in this way :

```
public string SettingsLogin
{
        get { return Resources.Settings_Login; }
}
```

Language switching code looks like following :

In PCL

```
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(lang);
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(lang);
Resources.Culture = new CultureInfo(lang);
```

In Win8.1 app

```
Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = lang;
```

Strings from LocalizationViewModel are consumed in Win8.1 application and it works pretty good, change of the language in the runtime as well.

**Problem occurs, when I create App package and install application. When I run installed application, language switch is not working.**

In resx files, I use embedded resource build action and I tried all combination of the build action and the "copy to output directory" setting.

Similar project you can find in [this article](http://suchan.cz/2013/09/shared-localization-for-windows-phone-8-and-windows-8-apps-using-pcl/)

Do you have any idea what can be the problem?

Comment: How did you set up your directory structure or file-naming convention?  I'm trying to do the same thing but having trouble getting the basic working.

Answer (score 1):

See the image linked below.
I ran into the same problem, change the setting to Never and it fixes the problem.

[image: SS]

Comment: Please note that links sometimes get broken over time, please add the name and location of "the setting" in the answer text.