# Translating strings within a PCL

Tags: c#, localization

I have in my project a series of localisation files. My current locale is in de-CH, but the schema from the server is in English.

Within my PCL, is there a way to convert the de-CH string into the English form?

The translations are in a standard resx file.

Comment: Related question? It seems to me it is possible? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25641567/portable-class-library-and-resx-localization

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

I created a PCL project with an English resource file in folder en-US:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  ...
  <data name="GoodMorning" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Good morning!</value>
  </data>
</root>
```

...and a Swiss resource file in folder de-CH:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  ...
  <data name="GoodMorning" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Guten Morgen!</value>
  </data>
</root>
```

This generates two wrapper classes that can be used directly, e.g.,

```
string english = en_US.Resources.GoodMorning; // Returns "Good morning!"
string swiss = de_CH.Resources.GoodMorning;   // Returns "Guten morgen!"
```

...which might answer your question. If not, the `ResourceManager.GetString` method has an overload that takes a `CultureInfo`; that might be a viable path as well.

All this assumes that you have the resource id; if you have the *value* of the Swiss string and want to find the corresponding English string, things get a bit more complicated. And the tools at your disposal depend on which platforms your PCL is targeting, of course.

---

### EDIT:

Given the Swiss string, you could do a lookup using reflection to get the property values. For simplicity, this assumes that the Swiss and English resources are exactly the same -- real-life code might have to handle missing strings in one or both languages:

```
public static string GetEnglishString(string swiss)
{
    Type englishResources = typeof(en_US.Resources);
    Type swissResources = typeof(de_CH.Resources);
    PropertyInfo[] infos = swissResources.GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
    foreach (PropertyInfo info in infos.Where(info => "Culture" != info.Name && "ResourceManager" != info.Name))
    {
        string value = info.GetValue(null, null) as string;
        if (value == swiss)
        {
            PropertyInfo englishProperty = englishResources.GetProperty(
                info.Name,
                BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
            string english = englishProperty.GetValue(null, null) as string;
            return english;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

This requires [System.Reflection.TypeExtensions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Reflection.TypeExtensions/4.1.0-beta-23516), available through NuGet. In real life, do this only once and set up a Swiss-to-English `Dictionary`. And pray that the set of Swiss strings don't contain duplicate values. :-)

Comment: It is the value that I have and I'm targeting 78